# как правильно настроить location в nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxy, location

Есть блог, расположенный на отдельном IP,  на нем поднят nginx на 443

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key;

    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


    index index.php index.html;
    server_name example.com;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    root /app/wp;

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all; # запрет для скрытых файлов
    }

    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
        deny all; # запрет для загруженных скриптов
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Необходимо сделать, чтобы на главном сайте путь /blog вел на данный ресурс

следующие варианты не работают:

## обрабатывается только главная

```
location  ~ ^/blog/(.*)$ {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
            proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1/$1$is_args$args;
        }
```

## запрос идет только к корневой дирректории /

## статика получает 404 и не доходит до источника

```
location  /blog/ {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1/;
}
```

## теряются get params

```
location  ~ ^/blog {
        proxy_pass https://52.51.81.133;
    }
```

категории и подкатегории не проксируются,
пробовал добавлять подкатегории отдельным location к примеру:

```
location  ~ ^/blog/tag/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1/tag/$1$is_args$args;
}
location  ~ ^/blog/category/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1/category/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

НО!! есть ещё пути со статьями вида:
/blog/статья-1
/blog/статья-2/
и что с ними делать не совсем понятно

Comment: может добавить звездочку еще одну `^/blog/(*.*)$`

Comment: nginx: [emerg] pcre_compile() failed: nothing to repeat in "^/blog(*.*)$" at "*.*)$" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/devmegabonus.conf:144
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Answer (score 4):

верно так:

```
location  ~ ^/blog {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

при такой форме регулярное выражение обработает все uri с /blog и отдаст $path в не обрезанном виде на proxy вместе с get парметрами